# Added a trigger function for inserts on a TABLE, but the function is not receiving the value from NEW.user_id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a Trigger function, and have added it to a table.
I've also tested the function to make sure it's firing by replacing my `NEW.user_id` value in the trigger function with a static one (user_id = 1) and it's being fired and the query inside the function as happening as expected.

What am I doing incorrectly that using `NEW.` doesn't get the value from the newly inserted row?

My Trigger Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_trigger() 
RETURNS trigger language plpgsql 
AS $$
    BEGIN
    
    WITH cte AS(
        SELECT * FROM test_user WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id
    )
    UPDATE test_username
    SET money_counter = money_counter + 1, 
        total_revenue = total_revenue + cte.revenue
    FROM cte
    WHERE test_username.username = cte.username;
    RETURN NULL;
    
    END; $$
```

Creating the Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger AFTER INSERT 
ON test_user EXECUTE FUNCTION test_trigger();
```

The Table I have added a Trigger function to:

[image]

Using an insert query to test the trigger function:

```
INSERT INTO test_user(
    user_id,
    username,
    revenue
)VALUES(
    1,
    'cooldude',
    1
)
```

Nothing happens to my `test_username` table which the Trigger function was supposed to update.

[image]

I try it again by changing the trigger function to a static value of `1` for the `user_id` and the trigger function updates it as expected:

[image]

```
INSERT INTO test_user(
    user_id,
    username,
    revenue
)VALUES(
    1,
    'cooldude',
    1
)
```

[image]

Why isn't my `NEW.user_id` in the dynamic trigger function receiving the value from the newly inserted row into my `test_user` table?

Comment: The bigger question is why you are using a `CTE` at all? Make the `UPDATE`  standalone and use `NEW.revenue`, `NEW.username`.

Comment: I did not read the `TRIGGER` well enough the first time through.  You have not specified a `FOR EACH` clause which means it falls  back to `FOR EACH STATEMENT`. Per the docs [plpgsl trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html), "NEW ...     This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations." Add `FOR EACH ROW` to trigger definition, per [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: That fixed my issue! Thanks. I can mark your answer as correct below if you'd like

Comment: What is the primary key of that table? This can probably be done much more efficiently using a BEFORE trigger and simply assigning the new values rather then using an UPDATE

Comment: I was using this as a small example to debug before trying it on my other query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger AFTER INSERT 
ON test_user EXECUTE FUNCTION test_trigger();
```

No `FOR EACH` clause was specified so the trigger fell back to the default of `FOR EACH STATEMENT`.

Per the docs [plpgsl trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) in the `FOR EACH STATEMENT` case:

> `NEW`
>
> Data type `RECORD`; variable holding the new database row for `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations in row-level triggers. This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for `DELETE` operations.

To get access to the `NEW` record change the trigger definition to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger AFTER INSERT 
ON test_user FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION test_trigger();
```